# How can I add an instance of a generic type to a list in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have been searching for a while to get a proper solution for this.

What I would like to do is add a specific number of empty objects to a list in the init method.

```
abstract class TypedMaxLengthMutableList<T>() : MutableList<T> {
    protected val innerList = mutableListOf<T>()
    protected val maxSize = 4

    init {
        for (i in 1..maxSize)
            this.innerList.add(???)
    }

    ... method overrides for MutableList
}
```

I've read about variants, invariants,covariants, types, classes, etc...

But so far I haven't been able to crack this one.

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: What’s the definition of empty object here

Comment: An empty object is an object from a class with a noargs constructor

Comment: How will you make sure that T provides the constructor?

Comment: That is an excellent question. I'll take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that there isn't any empty object for any type `T`.

You could pass this "default" object as a parameter:

```
abstract class TypedMaxLengthMutableList<T>(default: T) : MutableList<T> {
    protected val innerList = mutableListOf<T>()
    protected val maxSize = 4

    init {
        repeat(maxSize) {
            this.innerList.add(default)
        }
    }

    ... method overrides for MutableList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't invoke the constructor of T directly because generics are erased at runtime on the JVM; the compiled code will have no concept of what T refers to in each particular instance of TypedMaxLengthMutableList.

To solve this problem, you have the following options:

- Pass an empty object instance as a constructor parameter, as voddan suggests;
- Pass a lambda that creates an instance of T (`() -> T`), and invoke it for every element that you're adding
- Pass a `Class` or `KClass` instance representing the type of T and invoke its no-arg constructor through reflection.